# C# groupBox BackColor = transparent not working

Tags: c#, transparent, groupbox, backcolor

Hey I have created a form in c#. I made some groupboxes and set their BackColor to transparent, but there is still a backcolor. Anyone here who can help me solve this so I can make the groupboxes transparent?

```
        this.groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.BTN_Unlockall);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox4);
        this.groupBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft YaHei UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
        this.groupBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 47);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 95);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 336;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Tools";
        this.groupBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.groupBox1_Enter);
```

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4LKY.png)

Comment: IIRC "Transparent" in WinForms is an ugly hack which basically just draws the background of the _parent_ container in the child control. I haven't used WinForms in years but think it doesn't work with stacked hierarchical controls. You should post screenshots of the Document Outline and the Form itself so we can check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the groupbox is transparent doesn't mean there is no back color anymore.

There is still the back color of the parent container element containing the groupbox that might have a non-transparent back color.  Setting the back color of an element as transparent means making it transparent with respect to its immediate parent container element. (And then there might also the parent container of the parent container to be considered. And the parent of the parent of the parent container, etc...)

Comment: On top of the form I made a picturebox so I can set a GIF as background. Do you know how I can make it so the gif will be the full background?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the entities settings transparent in the whole group so it still looks the same.

Comment: You mean make every box in the form transparent?